# How do I install multiple versions of a package on FreeBSD?

Tags: software-installation, freebsd, postgresql

I currently have PostgreSQL 9.5 installed on my FreeBSD 11.4 box. I'd like to upgrade to PostgreSQL 13, and this will require a database migration. All the migration procedures I can find want to have both versions installed in parallel, but `pkg` wants to dump everything into `/usr/local/bin/`.

How do I go about getting both versions installed at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to have both installed at the same time. Dump the databases and then uninstall the old version and install the new one.

Comment: Thanks; I'll try that. I'd still be interested if there's a way, though.